# Line of Code in my Private Method is never Covered

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, moq, private-members

Below is piece of code of action method :

```
private static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetProductTypes()
{
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex filter = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("Prodcut1|Prodcut2|Prodcut3");
    var prodtypes = from ProdType e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProdType))
                    where filter.IsMatch(e.ToString())
                    select new { Id = (int)e, Name = e.ToString() };

    if (prodtypes  != null)
    {
        return prodtypes .Select(x => new SelectListItem
               {
                   Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                   Text = x.Name
               });
    }
    return new List<SelectListItem>();
}
```

Where : ProdType is enum.And which is containing some of the product types and it's values.

I have written unit test for that method :-

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetProductTypes_Test()
{
    //Arrange        
    PrivateType pvtType = new PrivateType(typeof(ProductController));
    //Act
    var actual = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)pvtType.InvokeStatic("GetProductTypes");

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>));
    Assert.AreEqual(3, actual.ToList().Count); //here : 3 = Product1,Product2,Product3
}
```

but when i checked its code coverage by code coverage option then its not covering the below line of code :-

```
return new List<SelectListItem>();
```

Can any one suggest me what i am doing wrong here ? And yes it's a private method that i am testing.Because i wanted to test all of private methods.

Comment: That line will never be covered, because `Select` by itself will never return `null`.

Comment: Many developers would disagree with you about testing private methods. They are the internal implementation, and should be free to change at will. You should only test the publicly-visible surface of the application. In the process, the private methods will be tested indirectly, by their effect.

Comment: You will suffer so much pain in the future for testing private methods like this, especially if you ever do some refactoring on their names...

Answer (score 0):

As Patryk already said: `prodtypes` will never be `null`.
To get 100% coverage you can adapt the method to one of the following (only second part - first part stays the same):

```
private static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetProductTypes()
{
    //select prodtypes
    if (prodtypes != null && prodtypes.Count() > 0)
    {
        return prodtypes.Select(x => new SelectListItem
               {
                    Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                    Text = x.Name
               });
    }
    return new List<SelectListItem>();
}
```

or the shorter and more performant one, as it should never be `null`:

```
private static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetProductTypes()
{
    //select prodtypes
    return prodtypes.Select(x => new SelectListItem
       {
            Value = x.Id.ToString(),
            Text = x.Name
       });
}
```

**BUT**
as mentioned by John: In most cases you should NOT unit test private methods, as they should be covered by some public interface/method. If it is not covered think about the method - maybe it is not even needed - happend to me a few times already.
But I also added the "in most cases", because there are cases where it could make sense to test private methods. In my case I have for example some error handling methods for my HW which is not attached during normal unit tests and so I call the "private error handler" directly to check if it behaves correctly. But your method does NOT look like such a case...

**UPDATE**
As suggested by Episodex a better solution for the method:

```
private static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetProductTypes()
{
    var filter = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("Prodcut1|Prodcut2|Prodcut3");
    return from ProdType e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProdType))
           where filter.IsMatch(e.ToString())
           select new SelectListItem 
               {
                   Value = ((int)e).ToString(), 
                   Text = e.ToString() 
                };
}
```

Comment: If `prodtypes` is never null then checking for `null` in your first example doesn't make sense. And instead of checking `.Count() > 0` you should use `.Any()` for better performance. But anyway your second example seems to be the only reasonable solution here. In fact this select could replace the one used in the linq query (why selecting twice?).

Comment: @Chrfin,as John mentioned private method should not test and it should be tested in public methods by its different behavior.But in my application there are so many private methods and due to this the code coverage of my controller is effecting.That's why i want to test private methods.And i also i am testing the different behavior of private methods in public methods unit testing.
>>So you are saying that i should use the second part approach ? But may be the cause of error if prodtypes is null then it will throw the exception.

Comment: @Pawan `prodtypes` cannot be null as LINQ will return empty list if nothing is to be selected, not null.

Comment: @Pawan: You should then test the controller actions in all different ways so the private methods are all called, but NOT call them directly. If you can't get all private methods called via the controller how should a user ever call them? And as already said: `prodtypes` can't be `null`, as the select never returns this. If no items match it will return an empty `IEnumerable` with 0 items, but NOT `null`...